# Create a PNG Resource dynamically

Tags: android, dynamic, resources, png

I'm trying in Android to get resources from an XML file sent from my server. It sends me a PNG file directly in Base64 format.

Like This :

lgrbehzlgrbezgbrhezugizgbrzbgre

My question is :

Is there a method to use the PNG data sent from my server as a resource like in "R.drawable.MyNewResource" ?

Or can I set ImageResoure from a PNG file in my application data folder ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, your question is not proper, If I am not wrong then you want something like,

Just convert your web response `base64 png string into bitmap` and then use that bitmap to set in imageview.

```
Bitmap bitmap;          
ImageView imgView;
byte[] decodedString;       

decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Sorry for forgot to mentioned, encodedImage is a string field, which contain base64 string for .png file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it seems like my png file is not correctly created by the bitmap factory. mHeight and mWidth both equals "-1", do you have any clue of the problem ?

Comment: Ok my bad, it was because of a mistake in Base64 type (NO_WRAP instead of DEFAULT in my case)

Answer (score 0):

You can create file and write your bitmap in file using this code.

```
File file = new File(imageDirectory,image_name);
OutputStream outStream = null;
try {
    outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();

    Toast.makeText(cameraActivity.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(cameraActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(cameraActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Bitmap will be saved in application file and then you can read it.